# C++, using external global variables in a namespace in multiple files

Tags: c++, namespaces, g++

I would like to use external variables as parameters in several c++ files. How do I use a namespace with external vars? Without the namespace everything works.

```
crack_detection_opencv.cpp:-1: In function ‘void ProcessArgs(int, const char**)’:
fillSobelSearchSize = std::stoi(optarg);
reference to ‘fillSobelSearchSize’ is ambiguous
```

Shortened code:

```
void ProcessArgs(int argc, const char** argv_orig)
{
    fillSobelSearchSize = std::stoi(optarg);
}
```

```
#pragma once

namespace cd
{
    float contrastAlpha = 5.8f; //unused
    float contrastBeta = -2.8f; //unused
    float contrastAlpha2 = 5.6f; //unused
    float contrastBeta2 = -2.8f; //unused
    int fillSobelSearchSize = 20;
}
```

```
using namespace cd;

extern float contrastAlpha;// = 5.8f;
extern float contrastBeta;// = -2.8f;
extern float contrastAlpha2;// = 5.6f;
extern float contrastBeta2;// = -2.8f;
extern int fillSobelSearchSize;
```

I tried to use external global variables as parameters in several functions and wrap them in a namespace. Without the namespace it works fine, but there are compilation erros if I use a namespace.

Comment: you expect `using namespace cd;` to somehow effect the following declarations?

Comment: You've got a global `fillSobelSearchSize` (see `extern int fillSobelSearchSize;`) and one in a namespace (`cd`). The compiler is telling you this.

Comment: It's very simple. ***Declare*** the variables as `extern` in a header file. ***Define*** the variables in one of the cpp files, and their values.

Comment: Oh so I switched the way it should be done. But I want to give define some start values in the header file for each variable, so I can use it as a library. This won't be possible with external variables, right? Or can I just set them to the value after using extern?